# How do I change the dll name when I dotnet publish?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile, .net-3.0

ALL of my .net core dockerfiles are 99% the same except for this last line:
`ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<APP NAME HERE>.dll"]`

seems pretty dumb of me because they could all be identical otherwise

Is there a way to change the dll name with the `dotnet publish -c Release -o out` command? can I do that without having to modify csproj files or anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this command to perform the build and rename the assembly:

```
dotnet msbuild -r -p:Configuration=Release;AssemblyName=foo
```

On Linux/macOS you will have to add quotes around the command, like this:

```
dotnet msbuild -r '-p:Configuration=Release;AssemblyName=foo'
```

However, there can be unintended side effects due to a [global property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties) being set. You should read this open issue from Sep 2019 as it speaks directly to your question regarding Docker and renaming the output: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/4696

Also, I know you wanted to avoid editing the .csproj file, but in case you aren't aware, you can add the `AssemblyName` property and set the output name in that manner.

Such as:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>foo</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This will create `foo.dll` (and other files as well, e.g. `.pdb`, `.deps.json`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) suggests:

> You can override the ENTRYPOINT instruction using the docker run --entrypoint flag.

The command will look something like this:

```sh
docker run --entrypoint dotnet YOUR_IMAGE "<APP NAME HERE>.dll"
```

OR

As another [helpful bit of documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options) suggests, that you can also pass arguments to the entrypoint at the end of `docker run` command like so:

```sh
docker run YOUR_IMAGE "<APP NAME HERE>.dll"
```

This will also require you to change your `ENTRYPOINT` to:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @gcamp806's answer: I couldn't get the command to run under Windows 10 when using `;` between the arguments. Instead I had to use a normal comma: `,`

My command to publish a self-contained executable now looks like this:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 /p:Configuration=Release,PublishSingleFile=true,IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true,AssemblyName=appname --self-contained --output ./releases/windows/v1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using

```
ARG SERVICE_NAME
RUN ln -s "${SERVICE_NAME}.dll" docker_service_name.dll
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "docker_service_name.dll" ]
```

So far it hasn't caused any problems and I cannot find any issues with it when I google - closest I come is some old trouble people had running dotnet executables through shortcuts on *Windows* which is not my base layer so I'm good. So far.